# When was my gsettings altered last?

Tags: gnome, suspend, power-management, gsettings

Ubuntu 18.04.

I set the following command to stop my laptop from suspending, but it appears that it has reverted to the default setting of 1800 when I recently checked.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-timeout 0
```

Is there a way to check when the last edit was done? Is this setting saved in a file somewhere that I can check the modification date of?

Is it possible that some Ubuntu update has restored it to the default setting?

Comment: If it happens more often, You could run a tiny background proc to find out when settings change. does it?

Comment: @JacobVlijm what can you run to log changes?

Comment: I kind of want to know what's happened in the past up to now, not if it happens again...